# Create a layer with increasing height - swift

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

I want to make a custom slider that has increasing height i.e it's height starts from 4.0 and goes to 6.0.

[image]

I have written code for creating a layer but I cannot find a way to increase its height in this manner. Here is my code :

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
    ctx.addPath(path.cgPath)

    ctx.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
    ctx.fillPath()

    let lowerValuePosition = slider.positionForValue(slider.lowerValue)
    let upperValuePosition = slider.positionForValue(slider.upperValue)
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,
                      width: (bounds.width - 36),
                      height: bounds.height)
    ctx.fill(rect)
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to have a slider "background" that increases height? Like a "wedge"? Or are you trying to increase the height of something based on the position of the slider?

Comment: Yes I mean the slider height should increase like a wedge.

Comment: OK - I'd suggest that you edit your question, and try to be a little more detailed. Do you want a static "wedge" background, over which the thumb slides? Do you want no thumb, and essentially drag the edge the wedge to make it "grow"? Do you want the horizontal slider line to also show? It would help if you added an image or two of exactly what you want.

Comment: @DonMag Thanks for your inputs and time. I've added an image of the slider .
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Minimum and Maximum (left-side & right-side) "Track" images stretch, you may not be able to get what you want with a default `UISlider`.

Not too tough to get around it though.

Basically:

- create a custom view with your "rounded wedge" shape
- overlay a `UISlider` on that custom view
- "fill" the percentage of the shape when the slider value changes

Here's the idea, *before* overlaying them:

[image]

When we want to overlay the slider on the wedge, set the slider Min/Max track images to clear and it looks like this:

[image]

We can use a little trick to handle "filling" the shape by percentage:

- use a gradient background layer
- mask it with the shape
- set the gradient colors to `red, red, gray, gray`
- set the color locations to `[0.0, pct, pct, 1.0]`

That way we get a clean edge, instead of a gradient fade.

Here's a complete example -- no `@IBOutlet` or `@IBAction` connections, so just set a view controller's custom class to `WedgeSliderViewController`:

```
class RoundedWedgeSliderView: UIView {

    var leftRadius: CGFloat = 4.0
    var rightRadius: CGFloat = 6.0

    // mask shape
    private var cMask = CAShapeLayer()

    var pct: Float = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            let p = pct as NSNumber
            // disable layer built-in animation so the update won't "lag"
            CATransaction.begin()
            CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
            // update gradient locations
            gradientLayer.locations = [
                0.0, p, p, 1.0
            ]
            CATransaction.commit()
        }
    }

    // allows self.layer to be a CAGradientLayer
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { return CAGradientLayer.self }
    private var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer {
        return self.layer as! CAGradientLayer
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        // gradient colors will be
        //  red, red, gray, gray
        let colors = [
            UIColor.red.cgColor,
            UIColor.red.cgColor,
            UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0).cgColor,
            UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0).cgColor,
        ]
        gradientLayer.colors = colors
        // initial gradient color locations
        gradientLayer.locations = [
            0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
        ]
        // horizontal gradient
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let r = bounds
        // define the "Rounded Wedge" shape
        let leftCenter = CGPoint(x: r.minX + leftRadius, y: r.midY)
        let rightCenter = CGPoint(x: r.maxX - rightRadius, y: r.midY)
        let bez = UIBezierPath()
        bez.addArc(withCenter: leftCenter, radius: leftRadius, startAngle: .pi * 0.5, endAngle: .pi * 1.5, clockwise: true)
        bez.addArc(withCenter: rightCenter, radius: rightRadius, startAngle: .pi * 1.5, endAngle: .pi * 0.5, clockwise: true)
        bez.close()
        // set the mask layer's path
        cMask.path = bez.cgPath
        // mask self's layer
        layer.mask = cMask
    }

}

class WedgeSliderViewController: UIViewController {

    let mySliderView = RoundedWedgeSliderView()
    let theSlider = UISlider()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(mySliderView)
        view.addSubview(theSlider)

        mySliderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        theSlider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // constrain slider 100-pts from top, 40-pts on each side
            theSlider.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 100.0),
            theSlider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            theSlider.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),

            // constrain mySliderView width to the slider width minus 16-pts
            //  (so we have 8-pt "padding" on each side for the thumb to cover)
            mySliderView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theSlider.widthAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            // constrain mySliderView to same height as the slider, centered X & Y
            mySliderView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theSlider.heightAnchor),
            mySliderView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theSlider.centerXAnchor),
            mySliderView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theSlider.centerYAnchor),

        ])

        // set left- and right-side "track" images to empty images
        theSlider.setMinimumTrackImage(UIImage(), for: .normal)
        theSlider.setMaximumTrackImage(UIImage(), for: .normal)

        // add target for the slider
        theSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.sliderValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

        // set intitial values
        theSlider.value = 0.0
        mySliderView.pct = 0.0

        // end-radii of mySliderView defaults to 4.0 and 6.0
        //  un-comment next line to see the difference
        //mySliderView.rightRadius = 10.0

    }

    @objc func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        if let s = sender as? UISlider {
            // update mySliderView when the slider changes
            mySliderView.pct = s.value
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the `trackRect` method of your superclass `UISlider` in the subclass like below and return the bounds and size that you require:

```
/**
 UISlider Subclass
 */
class CustomSlider: UISlider {

    override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(origin: #oigin#, size: CGSize(width: #width#, height: #height#))
    }
}
```

Comment: That will give me a UISlider with new height. But what I want is that my slider has to start with a height of supposing 4.0 and end with height of 6.0.